# Can't parse request data in Flask when running over SSL

Tags: python, ssl, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have a Flask based app running which had a path responding to a POST command.  The incoming data was json so I used the get_json() method to parse the data.

I have now changed the server to run nginx and uwsgi as I now use SSL.  All paths in the app work (GET) but the POST based path no longer sees the incoming data as python and fails. The data is visible in request.data but the get_json method fails.

```
@school_app.route('/school/queries', methods=['POST'])
def school_queries():
    req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
    command_name = req["result"]["parameters"]["command-name"]
```

I have also tried to push the request.data through json.loads but this fails as well.

```
req = json.loads(request.data)
```

I'm assuming that the server changes have impacted the data but I can't see why it can no longer be parsed as json.

Comment: Had you try add headers={'content-type': 'application/json'} in your call?

Answer (score 0):

So, the following code works...

```
data = request.data
req = json.loads(data)
command_name = req["result"]["parameters"]["command-name"]
```

Still not sure why the get_json method stopped working after the switch to SSL/nginx/uwsgi but at least it works.